# How can I export an xarray dataset that is leading to a __truediv__ error?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray dataset that is concatenated from a bunch of files.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:               (hru: 17, time: 233)
Coordinates:
  * hru                   (hru) int64 9 17 11 8 3 2 6 4 7 12 1 13 10 16 15 5 14
  * time                  (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-01 ... 2010-01-30
Data variables:
    pptrate               (time, hru) float64 9.241e-05 9.241e-05 ... 2.717e-09
    hruId                 (hru) int64 dask.array<shape=(17,), chunksize=(1,)>
    averageInstantRunoff  (time, hru) float64 9.241e-05 9.241e-05 ... 2.717e-09
    nSnow                 (time, hru) int32 dask.array<shape=(233, 17), chunksize=(233, 1)>
    nSoil                 (time, hru) int32 dask.array<shape=(233, 17), chunksize=(233, 1)>
    nLayers               (time, hru) int32 dask.array<shape=(233, 17), chunksize=(233, 1)>
```

When I try to export this `ds.to_netcdf('test.nc')`

I get this error message:

`TypeError: cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>`

Not sure what the issue is.

This is the code that generates `ds`

```
import xarray as xr
import glob, os

NCDIR = './output/out/'
finalfile = 'summaout.nc'

outfilelist = glob.glob((NCDIR+'/*{}*.nc').format('basin_*timestep'))

ds=xr.open_mfdataset(outfilelist, concat_dim='hru')

replace = ds['pptrate']
runoff = ds['averageInstantRunoff'].values
runoff = np.squeeze(runoffdata, axis=2)
runoff = runoff.transpose()
replace.values = runoff

ncconvert = ds.drop('averageInstantRunoff')
runoffarray = xr.DataArray(runoff, dims=['time','hru'])
ds['averageInstantRunoff'] = runoffarray
ds.to_netcdf('test.nc')
```

Comment: I see you also posted this on the xarray issue tracker (https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2623) -- I'll answer over there

Comment: @shoyer Thanks! I'll direct my questions there from here on.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Pandas to Numpy to latest versions.